# how to set html5 slider defaults from localStorage?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I'm using pure html5 sliders as such:

```
<div>Brush Size:<input id="brush_size" type="range" value="10" min="1" max="100"/></div>
<div>Opacity: <input id="opacity" type="range" value="0.8" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="1.00"/></div>
```

Then saving the values into localStorage onChange:

```
$("#brush_size").change(function(){
  localStorage['brush_size']=this.value; 
});
$("#opacity").change(function(){
  localStorage['opacity']=this.value; 
});
```

After changes, on the next page load I would like to see the current localStorage values, instead of the html hardcoded values.  What's the best way of doing this?

I suppose I could set the slider's value to the localStorage values during page load using jQuery... is this the best-practices way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your code

```
$("#brush_size").val(localStorage['brush_size']);
$("#opacity").val(localStorage['opacity']);
```

Comment: very simple.  I chained that to my existing jQuery selector and it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should suffice:

```
$(function ()
{
    var ids = ['brush_size', 'opacity' /* etc */],
        id,
        value;

    for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
    {
        id = ids[i];
        value = localStorage[id];
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined')
        {
            $('#'+id).val(value);
        }
    }
});
```

---

Side note: you should probably be using `$(this).val()` instead of `this.value` in the `change` callbacks, and you can make that code more concise overall:

```
$('#brush_size, #opacity').change(function ()
{
    localStorage[this.id] = $(this).val();
});
```

---

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/G59QH/ (courtesy of [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347216/david-ipsen))

Comment: thanks.  I used this.value instead of $(this).val() because I figured there is no reason to invoke jQuery wrapping just to get the value.

Comment: @sketch AFAIK `.val()` is not equivalent to `.value`. As I understand it, the `value` **attribute** only contains the **initial value** of the input. If the input value changes, `.value` will only ever contain the initial input value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#attr-value